# Complex conjugate and unitary complex conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces, inner-product

**Definition:** Let V be complex finite dimensional inner product space
Complex Conjugate: $J$ is called complex conjugate on V iff  $(i) J$ is antilinear $(ii) J^2 =I$

**Definition:** Anti-unitary Complex Conjugate:  $K$ is called complex conjugate on V iff  $(i)$ $K$ is antilinear $(ii) J^2 =I (iii) <Ku, Kv> = <v, u>$

**Question:** Let $T$ be linear transformation on V such that there exist a complex conjugate $J$ on V such that $JTJ = T$. Can we find an Anti-unitary complex conjuagte $K$ on V such that $KTK = T$?

---

**Extra Comments**

This led me to question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678399/v-complex-ips-and-lt-with-real-matrix-entries

And complec conjugate may not imply unitary complex conjugate is proved in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678401/a-conjugate-lt-in-an-inner-product-space/

Comment: If  a  map preserve the complex inner product, it is necessarily  linear(can not be anti linear).

Comment: @AliTaghavi see carefully it is not preserving inner product

Comment: sorry I did not see carefully.